# android - deleting item from database with contextmenu

Tags: android, database, contextmenu

As the title says, I have a list which on long press gives an option to delete an item in the list from the database. When I run the code, nothing happens and I get a warning "window already focused, ignoring focus gain".
here are the code snippets -

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
} 


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.remove:
      System.out.println(sindex);

      db.open();
      db.deleteIP(info.position); //deleteIP is the method to delete item from list
      db.close();



      return true;
  default:
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

deleteIP() -

```
public boolean deleteIP(long _id)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + _id, null) > 0;
}
```

is `db.deleteIP(info.position)` creating the problem ?
I tried one more option. I have stored the index of the list item in sindex. So calling `db.deleteIP(sindex)` should have worked. But it doesnt!

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: did you check if data was removed from db ? prolly yes, but you didn't refresh adapter

Comment: how should i check if data was removed?

Comment: hmm you don't understand your own code ? check what deleteIP returns or rerun application to see if row is still there

Comment: I tried that too.. doesnt work :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing `info.position` and are then trying to use it as the primary key, which is probably not correct. If you are using a `CursorAdapter`, then `info.id` will contain the `_ID` value from your `Cursor`.

Comment: so in the case of an ArrayAdapter what should be the solution?

Comment: @mikdedroid: The `info.position` value is the index into the array.

Comment: i know, you said to use CursorAdapter to get the _ID, but how if it is ArrayAdapter?

Comment: @mikedroid: **The `info.position` value is the index into the array.**